# Sessão inteligente com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com CodeIgniter, PHP e MySQL. A sessão do usuário sempre foi tratada conforme o padrão do CodeIgniter, porém agora necessito que a sessão seja mais restritiva, funcionando de maneira análoga à uma sessão de internet banking, expirando em sete minutos (420 segundos) de inatividade, sendo que a cada requisição do cliente com o servidor esses sete minutos são renovados.

Não sei se nativamente apenas definindo parâmetros o CodeIgniter oferece suporte para essa forma de armazenar a sessão, porém não tenho conseguido representar essa forma de trabalhar.

Não sei se para este nível de restrição preciso reimplementar alguns métodos da classe CI_Session, ou se basta apenas definir corretamente os parâmetros do CI?

Em caso negativo, será que já existe uma classe ou plugin do CodeIgniter que já tenha uma atividade como essa implementada?

Exemplo de como estou configurando os parâmetros:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 420; 
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']          = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']            = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']         = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']          = 420;
$config['sess_storage']                 = 'database';
$config['sess_database']                = 'default';
$config['sess_timeout']                 = 7200;
$config['sess_destroy_on_timeout']      = FALSE;
$config['sess_update_interval']         = 180;
$config['sess_gc_probability']          = 10;
$config['sess_http_only']               = FALSE;
$config['sess_secure']                  = FALSE;
$config['sess_forwarded_ip']            = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver o problema simplesmente reorganizando a configuração da sessão do CodeIgniter, definindo no arquivo `config.php` da minha aplicação os parâmetros para o funcionamento da sessão.

Basicamente, consultei novamente a documentação do CodeIgniter e removi alguns dos parâmetros que ficaram em desuso a partir da versão 2.0.

Utilizei as orientações de cada parâmetro da sessão do CI definidas na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em minha aplicação, os parâmetros referentes a configuração da sessão ficaram da seguinte forma:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']             = 'fwsibe';
$config['sess_expiration']              = 7200; 
$config['sess_expire_on_close']         = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']          = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']            = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']              = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']                = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']         = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']          = 0;
```

Cheguei à esta solução graças ao seguinte post no stack overflow internacional:
[CodeIgniter Session equal to Internet Banking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549223/codeigniter-session-equal-to-internet-banking)

Answer (score 2):

Creio que CodeIgniter não possua isso, mas isso é muito simples. Qualquer requisição feita no aplicativo onde qualquer página que contenha `session_start()` no começo, a sessão irá se renovar e começar a contagem novamente, ou seja, irá fazer a função que você quer.

Se o usuário ficar parado na página preenchendo e enrolando e etc, ele pode ser deslogado, exato? Então também ou pelo menos uma outra forma de evitar isso, é que você tenha uma função AJAX, que chame alguma página qualquer que contenha `session_start()` para renovar a sessão caso ele ainda tenha a página aberta. Mas essa situação pode variar muito, como em uma Lan House acabar o tempo da pessoa, e em algumas os browsers continuam aberto dependendo do sistema da Lan.

Então é bom pensar em alguma lógica para gerenciar seu aplicativo.

Comment: pois é, no caso do CodeIgniter o session_start() não é aplicável. Porém já resolvi este problema no qual encontrei a solução simplesmente reorganizando a configuração da sessão do CodeIgniter.