# Validação de ID Recebido pela Form - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, segurança

Olá, sou programador PHP, e tenho uma dúvida recorrente, já li alguns livros mas ainda nada me ajudou de forma concreta, você pode validar no back-end qualquer coisa, mas no form que o user preenche, sempre terá que vir a informação do ID dele, para que eu possa através do ID pesquisar na database e fazer toda validação de dados cruzados, mas como eu posso validar que o ID que veio é realmente do usuário que enviou, e que ele não alterou via inspecionar ou javascript seu ID para o de outro usuário ou qualquer ?, pois isso deve ser feito antes das outras validações, reparem que recebo $usuario, mas não posso confirmar se o que veio é realmente o usuário que solicitou, e que não foi alterado.

```
<?php
ob_start();
require 'conexao.php';

//Deus é fiel o tempo todo

$validar_form = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['action19129219129']);

//checar existencia
if (isset($validar_form) AND $validar_form == '8278812712872') {

//usuario 
$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
//ponto de retorno 
$retorno = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['retorno']);
//valor inserido pelo usuario
$valor_usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['valorchangecontratual']);

//buscar usuario
$buscar = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$usuario'";
$execultar = $mysqli->query($buscar);

//procedencia de retorno
$search = $execultar->num_rows;

if ($search > 0) {
  $var = $execultar->fetch_assoc();

  $saldo_rendimento = $var['saldo_rendimentos'];
  $saldo_real_contratual = $var['saldo_indicacoes'];

//validacao de valor
  if ($valor_usuario > $saldo_real_contratual OR $valor_usuario < 0) {
    header('location: ../login.php?con=Operação Inválida');
    die();
  }
 
$transferir = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET saldo_rendimentos = saldo_rendimentos + ? WHERE id = ?");
$transferir->bind_param("di", $valor_usuario, $usuario);
$transferir->execute();
$transferir->close();

$debitar = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET saldo_indicacoes = saldo_indicacoes - ? WHERE id = ?");
$debitar->bind_param("di", $valor_usuario, $usuario);
$debitar->execute();
$debitar->close();


 if ($transferir AND $debitar) {
    header('location: '.$retorno.'?con=Transferência Realizada Com Sucesso');
 } else {
    header('location: '.$retorno.'?con=Erro De Processamento, Tente Novamente Mais Tarde');
 }

} else {
    header('location: ../login.php?con=Operação Inválida');
    die();
}

} else {
    header('location: ../login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Esse usuário que submete o form não está logado no sistema?

Comment: O form é enviado de uma página dentro do codeigniter, para uma página de processamento sem sessão fora do codeigniter..

Comment: O id é informado pelo próprio usuário ou é um campo do tipo hidden dentro do form?

Comment: campo do tipo hidden, preciso garantir que o valor dele que chegue ao arquivo de processamento, não foi alterado pelo F12 ou javascript ou afins, o user pode dar F12 e mudar o value do input hidden com ID dele para qualquer numero ou valor, e preciso garantir que o que chegue seja o ID, ou ter como verificar que não é.

Comment: Bom, já que não tem informação do login na sessão para comparar ou buscar e usar, uma forma de resolver seria usar criptografia, você pode por exemplo usar `openssl_encrypt` e `openssl_decrypt`, para gerar uma criptografia personalizada para o seu sistema. Se não conseguir descriptografar a informação quando receber o post, significa que o usuário tentou alterar o id, mas não conseguiu por não saber como você encriptou.

Comment: É uma boa ideia, você sabe se existe forma de conectar a sessão do CodeIgniter a arquivos php externos ?

Comment: Sinceramente não sei, não tenho experiência com CodeIgniter, tem uma resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38019/sess%c3%a3o-inteligente-com-codeigniter, que diz que é só colocar `session_start();`, mas ela é muito antiga e não sei se é valida. Os frameworks costumam ter sua própria forma de armazenar informações de login e sessão, como dito aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110127/%c3%89-ruim-usar-o-mecanismo-padr%c3%a3o-de-sess%c3%a3o-do-php.

Answer (score -3):

O ideal é não dar o poder do usuário enviar o id dele, você pode receber o id pela session, caso esteja logado.